# How to display nodes of specific terms and expose only those terms to the user (out of many other terms)

Tags: views, 8

I have created a view, where I display two content types. Both of them have field "Country". So in my view I want to display only nodes related to three particular countries, but additionally I want to add filter, so that the user is able to see content only for one country out of the three.

The problem is that when I specify in "Filter criteria" show nodes only for these three countries it works, but when I make this filter "exposed" the view renders absolutely all nodes.

At the same time I want my exposed filter to have only the 3 countries available available.

Comment: perhaps there is another view that messes the view up ? or describe in more detail your view / content type setup ...

Comment: I have two content types. Both of them have field "Country" (the filed is re-used) what is the reference to taxonomy term. I need to create a view, where I need to display the nodes (Image, Title, Description) of this two content types, which are related only to three countries

Answer (score 1):

An exposed filter has no effect by default, so your simplest solution is to add another filter *that is not exposed* that limits the view to just the countries you want.

It's a useful trick with views to combine exposed and not-exposed filters and sorts.

Comment: When the view is loaded it seems right, but it disabled the filter. I can not filter the results depending on the country

Comment: I don't know exactly what version of Drupal you are using but I just created a view from scratch in Drupal 8.5.5, following these instructions but using content types and taxonomies already existing on the site, and it worked exactly as expected. When you say it disabled the filter, please explain exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a setup that does not seem to create any trouble. The country is a `taxonomy term` field attached allowing only 1 country to be specified per node.

When the filter is exposed you can specify the countries to be displied/filterable and you can also limit the list to those countries

Here is a working setup

[image]

and here what you will see vising the page of this view

[image]

only the specified countries are displayed and it works as it should

Comment: If I do it the same way, it also works. But then in filter it shows all taxonomies for country field, But I need just three countries in the filter. And that's why I also check "Limit list to selected items" and this breaks the view

Comment: Make that known in your question please

Comment: With all that setting, when I apply the filter /collections?field_country_target_id=968 it returns me again all existing nodes

Comment: perhaps you have a module that messes with your view ... try to do this on a new drupal 8 installation or try to disable all modules that might be doing harm.